# Why is Python truncating perfect float values?

Tags: python, floating-point, ieee-754

I know that Python's `float` type is actually a `double`.  Knowing that, I'm having a hard time understanding the results shown below.  My expectations are based on the output of https://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/ and https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html.  What is going on here?

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.float_info
sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308, min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)
>>> 
>>> decimal_value = 1.23450005054473876953125  # This number is perfectly represented by a 32 bit float.  No rounding necessary.
>>> type(decimal_value)
<class 'float'>
>>> decimal_value
1.2345000505447388  # Why did Python truncate this?
>>>
>>> decimal_value = 1.2345000505447389915758549250313080847263  # This number is perfectly represented by a 64 bit double.  No rounding necessary.
>>> # The comment on the line above is a lie.  That number is not a perfect double.  The closest perfect double to that value is 1.2345000505447389915758549250313080847263336181640625
>>> type(decimal_value)
<class 'float'>
>>> decimal_value
1.234500050544739  # Why did Python truncate this, and why isn't this truncated double value the same as the trucanted float value above?
```

Comment: Because of the default precision that it uses when printing floats. Use a format string with longer precision.

Comment: try `"{:.40f}".format(decimal_value)`. closing as duplicate as at least one answer solves your issue

Comment: both those numbers look **far** too long to be represented by even a double precision number, where did you get them from?  notice that `dig=15` in the `float_info`, i.e. a double can represent approximately 15 decimal digits, not the 23 and 40 you are trying with

Comment: The numbers are just values that show the problem I was having.  I verified them using the IEEE-754 calculators linked to in my question.

Comment: @SamMason There are some longer numbers that are exactly representable. 1.23450005054473876953125 is one of them. The closest exactly representable number to 1.2345000505447389915758549250313080847263 is 1.2345000505447389915758549250313080847263336181640625.

Comment: try printing the hex representations of your numbers (i.e. `value.hex()`) they are one bit apart for me, which is all that can be done.  python prints numbers using the shortest unambiguous decimal representation by default.  hence it "truncates" the number

Comment: @ubiquibacon It's lying, or at least rounding. If there is any digit after the decimal point the least significant digit must be 5. For integers A and B, A/(10**N) == B/(2**M) implies A is divisible by 5**N.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, I think I was reading or using the calculator incorrectly for the double number.  I realized that after I made the comment (tried to delete, but you are too quick!).  When use the calculator to generate the double from its corresponding hex value of `3FF3C08320000001` it works as expected.